# Is it impossible to accurately measure the health of a Lead-Acid UPS?

Tags: electrical-power, ups

In a [blog post from Schneider Electric](https://blog.schneider-electric.com/power-management-metering-monitoring-power-quality/2015/06/24/4-big-benefits-of-lithium-ion-batteries-for-ups-systems-and-2-key-challenges/) (parent company of APC, the UPS manufacturer), they say that lead-acid UPS batteries "rely on chemistry that makes it hard to accurately predict when they’re going to fail".

I haven't seen this documented anywhere else, although I have experienced unexpected UPS failure many times myself - even with UPS models that have a "replace battery" indicator.

Having had too many UPS backups fail without warning, I am looking for a reliable UPS: either a lead-acid UPS with a battery meter (not just an indicator LED), or a UPS with a lithium-ion battery.

Can I trust the battery meter on a lead-acid UPS?

Comment: Due to the physical design of Lead Acid batteries it is entirely possible for them to fail with no prior indication. It is pretty rare but it can happen.

Comment: Does this failure type have a name? Can you point me to more information about this type of failure?

Comment: Well it isn't just one specific failure type. For instance, sulfur shedding from the plates can cause shorts. Plates can warp and cause shorts or opens. Depending on the design you can get a build up of hydrogen and oxygen that can cause an explosion.

Comment: Still a bit confused: Explosions aside, couldn't these sort of shorts and opens be reliably detected ahead of time?

Comment: Well...sort of...A partial short from shedding would show as a drop in voltage that got worse over time. You wouldn't know that was the reason without taking the battery apart but you would know that there was ***some*** problem with the battery. An open caused by repetitive mechanical stress though would rarely have any indication that it was happening until you suddenly had 0v on the battery.